# Null Injector Error after migrating from Angular/ NgRx 13 to 15

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular15

After migrating from Angular/NgRx 13 to 15, we have encountered an error related to importing StoreModule.forRoot at the module level. Is there any solution to this issue?

Note that the @angular version is 15.2.2 & the @ngrx version is 15.2.1

[image]

Comment: This looks like an error in the production build. Could you please add the relevant parts of your root module (so we can see how you're importing the `StoreModule`) and try to get this error in a debug build so we can see which injectable is not being provided?

Comment: The error happened after ng serve. It is not about build. The main application is a huge app, so each module is handled by a separate team. Therefore, any module has its own store, and we import StoreModule.forRoot for every single module individually. Also we don't have anything regarding the Store in the app.module.ts. It was working with Angular 13 and before ..

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this. A single (even empty) `forRoot` is enough for any size app, you can always call `forFeature` anywhere and add any form of separate state. More context is needed to resolve this